# Close system dialog with applescript

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to click OK button on system dialog from applescript? Currently I have made all my workflow on it and only closing that dialog part is missing.
Dialog appears on Safari app (since I make my script to work on Safari) when button "stop reminders" clicked via Javascript function. It's confirmation dialog for destructive action (stoping reminders).

[image]

```
clickId("stop reminders button id") --clicking on button I need
delay 2 -- making sure that dialog has enough time to appear
pressEnterButton() --just trying to close it

to clickId(theId)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickId

to pressEnterButton()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end pressEnterButton
```

that's how I try to do it now, but it not works that way (it's sad, because when I press "enter" on keyboard, it works as it should and dismisses dialog).

Comment: Where is this dialog coming from. Are you asking Safari to display it within the same script. If are calling this dialog yourself then afaik you will not be able to click the button this way because the script will be waiting for a response from the dialog before the script runs any more code.  Please provide more details on what you are doing. And include code.

Comment: @markhunte if that is the case, Povilas should use `ignore application responses` when telling "Safari" to do something.

Comment: can you add more code? will request be confirmed then?

Comment: Is this dialog from a site. If so can you provide the webpage.

Comment: @ShooTerKo good point, I always forget about that. I have added within an answer

Comment: Yes, that helped, I was missing that block. Thank you guys, you're a life savers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ShooTeKo had a good point about wrapping the dialog part of the code in a

`ignoring application responses`  block

This does work with your existing code.

I tested using a adjusted html - javascript code snippet from [www.w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert)

( I added an id to the button. )

The html page to test on is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button id="myBtn" type="button"" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And you code adjusted.

```
clickId("myBtn") --clicking on button I need

delay 2 -- making sure that dialog has enough time to appear
pressEnterButton() --just trying to close it

to clickId(theId)
    tell application "Safari"
        ignoring application responses
            activate

            do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click()" in document 1
        end ignoring
    end tell
end clickId

to pressEnterButton()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end pressEnterButton
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
to pressEnterButton()
   tell application "Safari" to activate
   tell application "System Events"
      tell application process "Safari"
          keystroke return
      end tell
  end tell
end pressEnterButton
```

Comment: Jep, that's more complete than my answer. I'll delete mine and up vote yours :-D

Comment: Better to be safe than sorry. :) You really have to make sure that the application is active before trying to send keystrokes. :)

Comment: just tried this, still can get it work. Automator still timeouts after minute or so when alert is displayed. Displayed error "Safari got an error: AppleEvent timed out."

Comment: Then you should try like ShooTerKo said, wrap tell app Safari thar resider inside your clickId handler with an ìgnoring application responses` block, because then it hangs there, waiting for input, and not progressing passed the dialog box. HTH